# Complex integral computation

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate$$ \oint f\left( z \right )dz$$ 
where C is the unit circle 
$$\left | z \right |=3$$
$$f\left ( z \right )=\frac{1}{z^{3}+2z^{2}}$$
Let
$$z=3e^{it}$$
$$z^{3}=27e^{i3t}$$
$$dz=3ie^{it}$$
$$2z^{2}=18e^{i2t}$$

Substituting everything into the initial equation and reducing, we get $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{i}{9e^{i2t}-6e^{it}}$$

How should I proceed further?

Is it sensible to use the identity Cos(x)+iSin(x)=1 for the complex exponential?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCDI have performed an edit

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD What has this to do with holomorphic?

Comment: just one of the most important results of complex analysis: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem

Comment: But it isn't what the question was asking...
I used the identity and arrived at an answer.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD $f$ is certainly not holomorphic on the region bounded by $C$.

Comment: just to add, f is undifferentiable at z=0 so it is non-holomorphic..unless well...we do a circular 'cut' around z=0(but that's beside the point)

Comment: @Dr.MV Damn I'm sleepy, I somehow factored that horribly in my head.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I'm getting fatigued also.  Time to call it a night!  - Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to show that the value of the integral is zero.  If one wishes to proceed directly, then we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=3} \frac{1}{z^3+2z^2}\,dz&=\frac14 \oint_{|z|=3}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}+\frac2{z^2}-\frac{1}{z}\right) \,dz\\\\
&=\frac i4\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3e^{it}}{3e^{it}+2}\,dt+\frac i2\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3e^{it}}{9e^{i2t}}\,dt-\frac i4\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3e^{it}}{3e^{it}}\,dt\\\\
&=-\frac i4\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{3e^{it}+2}\,dt\\\\
&=-\frac i4\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3\cos t+2}{12\cos t+13}\,dt-\frac 14\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3\sin t}{12\cos t+13}\,dt\\\\
&=-\frac i2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{3\cos t+2}{12\cos t+13}\,dt-\frac 14\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{3\sin t}{12\cos t+13}\,dt\\\\
&=-\frac i2\left.\left(\frac{t}{4}-\frac12 \arctan\left(5\cot(t/2)\right)\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi}+\frac {i}{8}\left.\log\left(12\cos t +12\right)\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: What is wrong with the final equation in the OP?

Comment: I arrived at $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\frac{i}{9-6}=\frac{2 \pi i}{3}$$

Comment: The final equation in the OP is incorrect.  The denominator should be $9e^{i2t}+6e^{it}$

Comment: How did you arrive at $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i}{9-6}\,dt$?  That is not correct.

Comment: But isn't $$e^{i2t}$$=1? and $$e^{it}$$=1?

Comment: $e^{it}\ne 1$ unless $t$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$.  And $e^{i2t} \ne 1$ unless $t$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks. Time to revisit some notes

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I need to call it a night for now.  I'll check in tomorrow morning.  - Mark

Comment: there might be some calculation errors

Comment: Hey mate, I could have made the computational error. The paper went well.

Comment: Great!  Pleased to hear!

Comment: Ah! Thanks for reminding.

Comment: And thank you for the best vote!